# Center the Bibliography heading/title using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

How can I get the title 'Bibliography' to be centered on the page using biblatex.

I'm using the report class.  And I'm required to only have bibliography centered, not other sections.

I've tried a few things, all to no avail:

```
   \printbibliography[tile={\centering Title}]
```

or

```
\addto\captionsenglish{
   \renewcommand{\bibname}{\centering Title}
}
```

I should note that last one I've used before to center Table of Contents and other sections, but doesn't work here for bibliography.

I've tried a bunch of other things, none work.

Is there a way to center only the bibliography heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use `\defbibheading`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{\centering #1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now, please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/[minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to future questions. It not only spares those answering having to set up a working code for your problem, but it also supplies details you might not know are relevant. For example, for the above code I had to assume you are not using any `\printbibliography` options such as `bibintoc`, `bibnumbered`, `subbibliography`, `subbibintoc` etc. If any of those are used, the code would have to be adapted.

Comment: Thank, that works perfect. I will try to be sure to include MWE in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Quick and very dirty

```
\printbibliography[title={\hspace{190pt} References}]
```

Comment: Welcome. // That's truely "dirty", meaning, it will probably fail when you change the documents format.

Comment: Thank you :) 

If that should prove to be the case, you can simply adapt "190" (just an approximation btw) to whatever new value fits best.